# How to reformat reStructuredText?

Tags: vim, restructuredtext

I'm writing reST in vim, which handles line breaks for me (after 80 chars). However, since I frequently go back and edit the text before, lines get ugly again. For example, in tables, it's sometimes annoying to re-format a complete table just because you need a line break in some place.

So I wish I had a program that reads my ugly-but-correct reStructuredText and outputs it nicely formatted and wrapped.

I found that `pandoc in.rst -w rst` mostly works, but it has some drawbacks. For example

```
:author: John Doe
```

becomes

```
author
    John Doe
```

and title formatting is changed as well. Sadly, there seems to be no `rst2rst` or something similar. Does anyone have some advice?

Comment: That's fatal if it converts field lists into block quotes. Field lists are the best feature of RST and I use them all the time. There is so much `:name: description` content in everything. That kind of breaks `pandoc` for this task altogether IMO.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
setlocal formatoptions+=a
```

to turn on automatic formatting of paragraphs in vim.  Adding that line to the `ftplugin/rst.vim` file in your vim configuration directory should do it automatically whenever you start editing a `.rst` file.

If that reformats too much, it may improve things to also add the `w` option. That causes vim to only consider a paragraph to extend onto the next line when a line ends with a space. It will automatically put a space at the ends of lines that are automatically inserted.

Answer (score 1):

Use -s with pandoc if you want the title block to be handled better.